# How to download/extract Static resources files which is already available in Salesforce

Tags: static-resources

I want to download the static resource files from one of the salesforce environment and need to upload those static resource files into another Salesforce environment,
But I don't see any options to download the static resource files?
Kindly suggest me on this. it would be very helpful for me..
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the image below, click on view file and you'll be able to download the file. If you want to replace it, click on edit or delete.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response! I tried the same, i can view that file but i din't get any option to download it...

Comment: Try right clicking on the file to download it. It sometimes depends on the file type. For example, if it's a zip file, it will download automatically. You can also try the edit option for some file types.

Answer (score 2):

You got two options here

1. For a single Static Resource download, refer crmprogdev post above
2. For single or bulk Static Resources download, try [Satrang Mass File Download AppExchange App](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EcsAOUAZ&tab=e), which helps you to download Static Resources in a single zip file. This app also helps bulk download Files, Attachments, and Documents.

Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologies, the publisher of this Mass File Download AppExchange App.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the force.com migration tool for this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/

If this is a one time thing, then the force.com migration tool may be overkill. In which case you can just create a change set as well and upload that to the destination org: https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=changesets.htm&siteLang=en_GB

Answer (score 0):

if you want to  download/extract Static resources files which is already available in Salesforce

For Example, I uploaded CSV file in static resource and I want to download it on a button

Just Import like this that static Resource Name

import MassUplodTenderTemplate from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/MassUplodTenderTemplate';

### In LWC
HTML Code

### [image]

### JS Code

[image]